# How to do real time tweet classification

Tags: python, twitter, classification, tweepy

I am trying to do real-time tweet classification. For this purpose, I am using tweepy streaming class. I want to

- fetch one tweet,
- store it in a database, in my case its a text file.
- Read the text file and
- classify the tweet.

Problem is that my system keep on fetching tweets and saving it.  it doesn't move to the next step.
What should I do?

**Streaming code**

```
import tweepy
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        if not status.text.startswith('RT'):
            if 'https://t.co' not in  status.text:
                text=status.text
                with open("Output.txt", "w",encoding='utf-8') as text_file:
                    text_file.write(text)

# Initializing the tokens
def run_stream():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

    api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
    myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener,tweet_mode= 'extended')
    myStream.filter(track=['corona'],languages=["en"],encoding='utf-8')
```

**Classification**

```
def classify():
    f = open("Output.txt", "r",encoding="utf-8")
    return f.read(),clf.predict_proba(feat.transform([f.read()]))
```

**run the function**

```
run_stream()
classify()
```

The problem I am facing is that system keeps on running the first function and don't move to the next classification function.

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html:

> Streams do not terminate unless the connection is closed, blocking the
>   thread. Tweepy offers a convenient is_async parameter on filter so the
>   stream will run on a new thread. For example
>
> ```
> myStream.filter(track=['python'], is_async=True)
> ```

If you do this, I suspect you'll need to carefully manage the read and write access to Output.txt, as otherwise you may read the file when it contains a partial write. It may be better to use a purpose-built, thread-safe, queuing mechanism, like [Python queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html]).

Comment: so there is another way to return tweet of out tweepy with out storing in text file or database

Comment: A text file may be the simplest to understand, but not as easy to make thread-safe. A database, assuming it can handle simultaneous producer and consumer, might work fine.